# Harsh azure key-vault secret.name when requested o print

Tags: azure, gis, arcgis, azure-keyvault, password-encryption

I have checked for all related questions but have not found a suitable answer.

I have a keyvault secret successfully set and I am able to access and parse it into my ArcGIS online service using python without any problem using the following code;

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url="vaulturl", credential=credential)
secret = secret_client.get_secret("papa-mama-Secret")

gis = GIS("urlGIS", "AGOLaccountname", secret.value)
```

The issue is when I print `secret.value`, the secret key is displayed. I dont want this to happen for security reasons. Is there away to ensure it can be passed into the service but when printed the key comes out as special characters say ***** or ####?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you could not change the print method just for `secret.value`. So, disabling the `print` method is better.

You could use `blockPrint()` to disable `print`.

```
def blockPrint():
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
```

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting proposal and I thank you for it because I didn't have it in my trick's bag.  However I hoped Azure had inbuilt mechanisms that encrypt key if printed but decrypt it when parsed into inline code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample to print out the value of your secret.

```
## CALL TO KEY VAULT TO GET SECRET
secret = client.get_secret("test").value

## OUTPUT SECRET VALUE TO CONSOLE
print(secret)
```

Comment: please read the question again. My challenge is how to make sure any attempts to print outputs nonplain text.